# R Shiny - Updating Title of Plot Based on Button Press

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

all!

I am trying to get the title of an output plot in R Shiny to work. I am not sure if observeEvent() or eventReactive() (or something else) is the best choice.

Here is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "num", 
              label = "Choose a number", 
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  textInput(inputId = "title", 
            label = "Write a title",
            value = "Histogram of Random Normal Values"),
  actionButton(inputId = "uptitle",
               label = "Update title"),
  textOutput("titl"),
  plotlyOutput("hist")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  newtitle <- eventReactive(input$uptitle, {
    paste0(input$title)
  })
  output$hist <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data.frame(x = rnorm(input$num))) %>%
      add_histogram(x = ~x) %>% 
      layout(title = newtitle)
  })
  observeEvent(input$uptitle, {
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, with this code, there is just no title.

I understand the premises of the functions, but I don't know how they can work with Plotly here. Should I use something other than layout() to create the title?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `layout(title = newtitle())` You are missing `()`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I am actually surprised that I was so close lol. Thanks again!